# powershell cmd executed in ISE but not as ps1

Tags: powershell

I am facing a peculiar issue.

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | 
    Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion | 
        Format-Table –AutoSize > C:\temp\InstalledSoftwareList.txt
```

When I run the above command from ISE, it creates the file and provides the expected output to txt file.

But when I save as PS1 and run with double click or by opening powershell console and run, it just creates txt file with no output.
I tried changing the working directory, admin user etc but no use. Suggestions please

It is PowerShell 5 and Windows 2016 R2

Comment: Need run as administrator?

Comment: <<< I tried changing the working directory,admin user etc>>> as mentioned in my post, I tried as admin user too

Comment: Not sure about your system, but on mine, that first command doesn't work. If I use "Get-Item", I get the Uninstall key (not sure why you're putting a "*" after it, maybe you're expecting other keys?), but it has no properties. Try removing the redirection to file and see if the script outputs anything? Or would something like this? Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | ForEach-Object -Process { [PSCustomObject] @{ 'DisplayName' = $_.GetValue("DisplayName"); 'DisplayVersion' = $_.GetValue("DisplayVersion") } }

Comment: Oh, and FWIW, running "Get-Item HKLM:...." worked non-elevated on my system

Comment: Not “admin user”, “run as administrator”.  If you’re right clicking and choosing run with powershell, it won’t be elevated unless UAC is turned off. Sounds like this isn’t the issue, however.

Comment: It is a matter of troubleshooting and narrowing it down: what happens if you just enter `Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` in a PowerShell console?

Comment: @DarkMoon- Looks this is not a permission issue. #Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion| Format-Table –AutoSize > C:\temp\InstalledSoftwareList.txt is  not working  but Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion|  Out-File -Encoding utf8 C:\temp\InstalledSoftwareList.txt -append -width 300 -- works in ps1 . Hence something related to | Format-Table –AutoSize > C:\temp\InstalledSoftwareList.txt.

Comment: The non working code is  
#Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion| Format-Table –AutoSize > C:\temp\InstalledSoftwareList.txt
working code is 
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion|  Out-File -Encoding utf8 C:\temp\InstalledSoftwareList.txt -append -width 300
and issue only with ps1 but not with powershell ISE. I have work around now. Thanks for all ur inputs

Comment: Glad to hear it.  If you've come up with a workaround that works for you, you should put it in an answer and accept it so future searches can benefit from what you've found.  :-)